# How to put video playlist next to the video player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I made a web player for mp4 and mkv videos, it works but the problem is that I still can't keep the playlist next to the video player, right now the playlist is at the bottom of the video player, this is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#playlist {
    display:table;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
    //padding:8px;
}

#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
#videoarea {
    align:center;
    //float:left;
    width:630px;
    height:350px;
}
video {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.MenuBox {
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: #solid 10px #000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block
}
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MenuBox">
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/snk.mkv">SnK</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/titanic.mp4">Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic </li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/shutter.mkv">Shutter</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/ab1.mp4">AB1</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/ab2.mp4">AB2</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/d1.mp4">D</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to keep the video player centered and the playlist next to the video player (on the right of the video player), how should I do that?

Solved with the help of Nitin Suri: here's the complete code http://pastebin.com/YS2cGdG7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Don here you go with the updated CSS for the play list to display next to the video player.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.MenuBox {
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: #solid 10px #000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
.MenuBox:before,
.MenuBox:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.MenuBox:after {
  clear: both;
}
#videoarea {
  float: left;
    width:630px;
    height:350px;
}
#playlist {
  float: left;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MenuBox">
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/snk.mkv">SnK</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/titanic.mp4">Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic Titanic </li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/shutter.mkv">Shutter</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/ab1.mp4">AB1</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/ab2.mp4">AB2</li>
    <li movieurl="/mnt/usb/d1.mp4">D</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the video isn't centered yet, I want the video to be in the center of the screen, this is the result of your code: `http://s12.postimg.org/u0k04f8t9/angel_beats_bg5.jpg`

Comment: @Don you need to add fixed width to ".MenuBox" instead of "width: auto".

Comment: Still doesn't work, please take a look at: http://pastebin.com/5nbB7Q82 and try it on your webserver @Nitin Suri

Comment: @Don when I say add fixed width, I mean giving a certain numerical value. Try this: "width: 980px;"

Comment: I gave it 900px still doesn't work, please try the code on your own webserver first, http://pastebin.com/LtyibDFQ

Comment: Don the total width of the child items must not exceed the width of the parent div, hence if you see the play list going below the video player, you will need to assign a width to the "#playlist { float: left; width: 240px }". This should help you achieve the layout that you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69796/discussion-between-don-and-nitin-suri).